# 「やっぱいや」とどういう意味はなんですか

Tags: meaning

Is the meaning of this word something like "Whatever..."?

If so, can you please give me an example of how I would use it? :-)

Cheers!

Comment: Could you provide more context about when you might want to use this/where you've seen this? Also, please do indicate your research effort. Doing both of those will help you to get a better answer to your question, will make it more useful to others, and will safeguard it from being marked as 'off-topic' (https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) – as currently presented, your question is arguably a translation question without demonstrating prior research.

Comment: It is a shortened form of やっぱりいや.

Comment: I'm not even sure whether it's intended to be いや or いいや.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's actually, やっぱり、いいや。

やっぱり can mean 'having thought twice' (e.g. ハンバーガーを食べようと思ったけど、やっぱりぎゅうどんにします。).

いいや in this case is like 'I won't be bother about it'.

So, it's like 'as a second thought, I changed my mind'

Answer (score 0):

やっぱり、いや
on the other hand, no thanks.

Comment: Could you add more to your answer?  Here on this page, we try to do more than just translate, we try to teach the grammar principles involved as well.  For example, you could explain how you went from やっぱいや to やっぱり、いや.  I don't know that many beginners will easily recognize the connection without guidance.  Any detail you can add will also make your answer stronger, and more likely to get positive votes.  See: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/22352